# Load a usercontrol from a folder programatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was looking to load a usercontrol from a folder. I want people to be able to package an extension for my app. To do this, they'll have to create a c# user control and put the designer, code, and resx file into a folder. Then when they want to use their "extension", they'll select a folder from a folder selector (I have that) and my app will load their extension. I want to specifically pull out the user control and cast it into a usercontrol object. Am I able to do this and if so, how?

I looked around the internet and there doesn't really seem to be any close to this question. I wasn't able to create any script that could accomplish this. I don't even know where to start in this one. I know that I have to compile their usercontrol.

If this is not possible, the next best solution I can think of is maybe a precompiled usercontrol. If this is possible, how would I load that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to compile the sources, this can be done using the `System.CodeDom`. Other than that you should load the types from the assembly and test to see if there is a `UserControl` in there, load it up and add it to your form.

Here is some example of what i described:

```
public void LoadPlugin(params string[] sourceCodeFilesForUserControl)
{
    // Compile the source files
    CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
    parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
    // Add references that they can use
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll"); // important for UserControl 
    parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;

    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceCodeFilesForUserControl);
    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        // Handle compile errors
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                          ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                          ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";");
        }

        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        // The assembly we can search for a usercontrol
        var assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
        // If the assembly was already compiled you might want to load it directly:
        // assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files\MyTool\plugins\someplugin.dll");


        // Get the first type in the assembly that is a UserControl
        var userControl = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.BaseType == typeof(UserControl));

        // Create a instance of the UserControl
        var createdUserControl = Activator.CreateInstance(userControl, new object[] { }) as UserControl;

        // Add the created UserControl to the current form
        this.Controls.Add(createdUserControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is not a great way to display an error message in a Winforms app.